# DDS for ROS 2 on Windows Setup

Tags: ros, ros2, windows, dds

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi~

I did not succeed in  building ROS2 on Win 10

But I followed the direction on ROS 2 on Windows Setup and got foxy "installed".
https://ms-iot.github.io/ROSOnWindows/GettingStarted/SetupRos2.htm

After the installation, I could run the turtlesim.

However, I find that I know little about the DDS: where it locates, what type (OpenDDS? RTI?), and how to use it within ROS.

Has anyone tried DDS on windows?

Thanks for your advice

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/390191/dds-for-ros-2-on-windows-setup/) by [cshmilyc](https://answers.ros.org/users/84861/cshmilyc/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2021-11-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> https://ms-iot.github.io/ROSOnWindows...

About the link, I cannot see the proper Installation steps in this link. I would highly recommend having a look at the official Foxy steps.

https://docs.ros.org/en/foxy/Installation/Windows-Install-Binary.html

> However, I find that I know little about the DDS: where it locates, what type (OpenDNS? RTI?), and how to use it within ROS.

Just have a look at the official link of DDS installation,

https://docs.ros.org/en/foxy/Installation/Windows-Install-Binary.html

---

Originally posted by [Ranjit Kathiriya](https://answers.ros.org/users/63046/ranjit-kathiriya/) with karma: 1622 on 2021-11-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0